# Reading a text using python iterator __next__ but it is stopping after reading first line

Tags: python

I have a below code

```
class read_file():
    #constructor taking a file name
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__file=open(filename)
        self.__current_line=[]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            if len(self.__current_line)==0:
                self.__current_line=self.__file.readline().strip().split()
            word=self.__current_line.pop(0)
            return word
        except:
            raise StopIteration
```

I am reading a multiple line text file. Problem is that this code is reading only first line of the file. No other lines are printed. Any clue how to fix that

[Edit]: Code is stopping when it encounters blank line. It should not stop at blank line. What change is needed for this
Looking for answer in this

Comment: What happens if you read an empty line?

Comment: (Also, `except: raise StopIteration` is a really bad way of handling termination. It hides all kinds of bugs.)

Comment: It should not stop at blank lines

Comment: It should ignore the blank lines if there are any

Comment: It *should*, but does the code you wrote *actually do that*? Did you write any code that would handle blank lines that way?

Comment: No.  I am not aware how to write that

Comment: how about `yield` instead of `return` in `__next__`

Comment: It goes in infinite loop with yield

Comment: how `self.__current_line=self.__file.readline().strip().split() or ''`?

Comment: no its not working

Comment: can i ask why are you not using `readlines()` ?

Comment: It was part of requirement

Comment: @GhostOps no that doesn't make any sense